# Proofread strings with Qt Linguist

Tags: c++, qt, translation

Our main language is English, so we use `tr("Some english text")` all over the source code.
We also plan to translate it to several different languages - no problem with that.

Our customer wants to get all phrases from the source code and proofread them.
Of course, we should put those phrases back after proofreading.

How can we accomplish that in a proper way? Maybe Qt Linguist allow to export/import embedded localizable texts?

I guess the customer can just translate English into English and then we can use that English translation, but it's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it looks like I will have to update phrases (embedded into source code) by hand. Actually, it shouldn't take too much time. If I have time to write a script on Python I will update this post.

**UPDATE**

So, I made everything "by hand" with a little help from [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).

1. Find all matches in repository folder using the following regular expression `(.*)(tr\((\"(.+?)\")\))(.*)`
2. Copy the search results into new document
3. Using the same regular expression do the search again and replace each match with **\4** - this capture group represents text in tr("").

After receiving phrases from the customer after proofreading, it took 3-5 minutes to find differences with diff tool and update phrases in code.

Not a true-programmer way of resolving problems but worked for me and worked pretty fast!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Qt's `lupdate` utility (could be found in Qt's bin directory) that will extract all string literals from your sources into a xml (ts) file. The file can be opened with Linguist tool.
Note, that the utility considers only strings surrounded with `tr()` macro. Here is `luptdate` description:

> lupdate is part of Qt's Linguist tool chain. It extracts translatable
>   messages from Qt UI files, C++, Java and JavaScript/QtScript source
>   code. Extracted messages are stored in textual translation source
>   files (typically Qt TS XML). New and modified messages can be merged
>   into existing TS files.

**UPDATE:**

Another alternative is keeping all string literals definitions in a separate source file and update it once customer has corrected all strings. I believe this happens not so frequently, or even only once, so it would not be worth of much effort with translations etc.

Comment: Thanks, I know how it works. That's how we do translations from English to e.g. Spanish and then use Spanish.qm translation pack. But I need a convenient way to modify original English phrases. So, I can export them to .ts file and customer will correct them in xml. How can I import these phrases back to source code?

Comment: @Dalamber, as you said, you can apply English to English translation that will replace existing strings with new one that came from the customer.

Comment: I think the source code updating you'll have to by hand, or maybe do it semi-automatically with some scripted search and replace. I'm not aware of any ready-made tool for this.